# udisksd continuously logs to syslog an assertion error

Tags: udisks

/var/log/syslog is filled with this 4 times every minute or more.

```
udisksd[30855]: udisks_mount_get_mount_path: assertion 'mount->type == UDISKS_MOUNT_TYPE_FILESYSTEM' failed
```

How can I get more information about what is causing this?

Comment: Maybe my solution might help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193533/udisks2-udisksd-errors-in-syslog-how-to-investigate

Comment: in my case that was bacause I added lines mounting swapfiles from a partition in my fstab , something like :
/data1/swapfile none    swap    sw      0       0
/data2/swapfile none    swap    sw      0       0
as the answer says, apt purge udisks2 is the answer until they fix their bugs and error messages, you dont need this if you already purged snapd and lxd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not exactly figure this out, but perhaps part of what triggered this was my removal of both LXD and Snappy.

I learned recently (yes, a year and a half later) that I do not need udisks installed at all, because I'm not using LXD (or snapd?).

I solved this by `sudo apt purge udisks2`

Comment: I had the same problem, same error message, probably becaus he cant understand I mount /partition/swapfile as a swap in my fstab . I was unsure I was able to purge that thing, and since i already purged snapd and lxd . . . your answer have been very useful